# Cannot communicate with Google Server from an android app in HTC one device

Tags: android, google-api-java-client, google-drive-realtime-api

When I am trying Google Login and after that getting the AuthToken for accessing Google Drive in HTC one the following code would not allow to access any of the Google accounts.

Even if we already had looged in, the following code returns zero accounts.

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(context);

Account[] acs = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
```

On executing this in HTC one, acs contains 0 accounts.

This code had worked fine in other devices like: Samsung S3, HTC desire, Nexus 4, Sony Ericsson and returned the accounts logged in.

Can any one help me to fix this?